# error creating new symfony project

Tags: php

I have installed symfony with these two commands:

```
sudo curl -LsS http://symfony.com/installer -o /usr/local/bin/symfony
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/symfony
```

and when creating a new project with this command:

```
symfony new holaMundo
```

it returns me this error:

```
/usr/local/bin/symfony: línea 1: error sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado `newline'
/usr/local/bin/symfony: línea 1: `<!DOCTYPE html>'
```

Comment: Where did you get these commands from? https://symfony.com/installer => "The page you are looking for does not exist."

Comment: What was wrong with `sudo apt-get install php-symfony` ?

Comment: You are downloading something that you later execute through the unsafe `http://` protocol. Prefer `https://` when available (`s` stands for secure; it's encrypted: among other things, stuff cannot be tampered with while in transfer). Feel very uncomfortable when only `http://` is available.

Comment: i get this commands from the official symfony page. I tryed installing with sudo apt-get install php-symfony and still the same error

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed (As per the [symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html)):

1. PHP 7.2.5 or higher and these PHP extensions (which are installed and enabled by default in most PHP 7 installations): Ctype, iconv, JSON, PCRE, Session, SimpleXML, and Tokenizer;)
2. Composer

Then install symfony cli using wget as per [symfony docs](https://symfony.com/download)
Assuming you are in linux logged in as root:

```
    wget https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer -O - | bash; \
    mv /root/.symfony/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony; \
    rm -rf /root/.symfony/
```

Then run `symfony check:requirements` to check if you meet all the requirements, before running `symfony new holaMundo`.